# Css style not applied when having unused style before

Tags: html, css

I have a strange behavior which I do not understand. Very simple HTML with a class `unusedstyle` before the class `contentmain-style`. In this case the div won't get the green border! When deleting or ordering the `unusedstyle` after the `contentmain-style`. I tried on every browser with the same behavior.

why does this happen? is it forbidden to have empty unused styles before others? What do I miss?

Thank you for answering.

### Code Snippet

```css
.unusedstyle {
  
} 

.contentmain {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentmain">test</div>
```

Comment: The live demo in your question has a green border. When you provide an [MCVE] it has to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code snippet you provided is already working as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After .unusedstyle {} you have a strange character:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: GREAT, thank you so much. I've never thought about something like this. This solved it. I use np++ for coding and maybe copy-pasted something from the internet with an invisible strange character!

Answer (score 0):

Try copying your code to JSFiddle. It shows an invalid character after the last bracket of the unusedstyle. Once that one is removed and you run your code again it seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try using other editors. Using your code with brackets works without issues.

Answer (score 0):

after .unsedstyle  closing tag } you have an extra element which block your contentmain class

```css
.unusedstyle {
  
} 

.contentmain {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentmain">test</div>
```